# Is there any other way i can send more secure cookie rather than this

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-modules

```
VerifyUser.refreshToken = refreshToken;
       VerifyUser.save();
       res.cookie('access_token',accessToken,{maxAge:1000*60*60*24,secure:true,sameSite:'none'})
       res.cookie('jwt',refreshToken ,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:1000*60*60*24,secure:true,sameSite:'none'})
```

I'm expecting another way to send cookie that after a time the browser will automatic delete those or a clean way to send cookie